# Cant pass value from Controller to .blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying display all product name,
I am getting the error :

```
ErrorException in 4938c589ea3db6bab0c4c788473314a4 line 46:
Undefined variable: allproduct (View: C:\Server\WebDocs\CRUD\resources\views\product.blade.php)
```

[image: Error MSG]

I had try `return View::make('product',$allproduct);` and 
`return View::make('product')->with('product',allproduct);` also cannot, i don't know why, this is my first Laravel program.

in my **ProductController**

```
    public function index()
{
    // get all the Products
    $allproduct = Product::all();

    return View::make('product',$allproduct);
}
```

in my **product.blade.php**

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <td>No</td>
                  <td>Product</td>
                  <td>Actions</td>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          @foreach($allproduct as $key => $value)
              <tr>
                  <td>$key</td>
                  <td>{{ $value->product }}</td>
                  <!-- we will also add show, edit, and delete buttons -->
                  <td>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          @endforeach
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try passing variable like

```
   public function index()
{
    // get all the Products
    $allproduct = Product::all();

    return View::make('product')->with('allproduct', $allproduct);
}
```

and in view

what about just doing `@foreach($allproduct as $product)` and then in `<td>`, `<td>{{$product->product}}</td>`. and make sure your have `product` column in `db`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this,

```
return View::make('product', compact('allproduct'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying using this code in Controller:

```
return View::make('product')->with(['allproduct' => $allproduct]);
```

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
 return View::make('product')->with('allproduct',$allproduct);
```

blade:

```
 @foreach($allproduct as $key => $value)
              <div>
            {{ $key . ' => ' . $value }}
        </div>
          @endforeach
```